# CSS selector to invert selection

Tags: css, selector

Is there any advantage or disadvantage in using `:not()` over an inverted selector logic? May it be in performance, safety or browser support, which approach is recommended?

Either:

```
.imageSlider img:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Or:

```
.imageSlider img {
  display: none;
}

.imageSlider img:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's could be better to use `:not`.

```
<p class="my-paragraph">
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div class="something-else"></div>
    <div class="an-other-thing"></div>
    <div class="an-other-thing"></div>
    <div class="last-one"></div>
</p>
```

In this case, if you want to hide `everything` except div `.an-other-thing` it will be quicker to write :

```
.my-paragraph div:not(.an-other-thing) {
    display: none;
}
```

Instead of:

```
.my-paragraph div {
    display: none;
}

.my-paragraph div.an-other-thing {
    display: block;
}
```

In most of cases, a longer CSS means longer time to execute it

Answer (score -2):

As of January 2017, the :not selector is currently only supported by Safari browsers with a mere 11% global browser support. I would stay away from using it in production code.

Comment: You seem to be confusing [selector argument support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list) (which allows complex selectors inside `:not()` with [basic support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) (which allows only simple selectors, as are demonstrated in the code in the question). Basic support has 98%+ browser coverage.